# Infinite series index law confusion. Heres my proof attempt.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Say $\displaystyle \sum_{n=m}^{\infty} a_n$ converges to $x$ we need to show that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=m+k}^{\infty} a_{n-k}$ converges to $x$ for some integer $k$

**Proof**

We know $\displaystyle \sum_{n=m}^{N} a_n =\displaystyle \sum_{n=m+k}^{N+k} a_{n-k}$ and so $\displaystyle \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=m}^{N} a_n =\displaystyle \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=m+k}^{N+k} a_{n-k} $

where $S_N := \displaystyle \sum_{n=m}^{N} a_n$ this means $\displaystyle \lim_{N\to\infty} S_N  =\displaystyle \lim_{N+k\to\infty} S_{N+k} = x$ (since earlier we proved that the index for the limit notation is arbitrary)

Hence $\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} a_n = \sum_{n=m+k}^{\infty} a_{n-k} = x$

for some reason i don't feel convinced does anyone have any thoughts? Perhaps I'm wrong i seem to be kind of confused at writing  this part: $\displaystyle \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=m+k}^{N+k} a_{n-k} = \sum_{n=m+k}^{\infty} a_{n-k} $

Comment: What you have done is correct. Basically the two series are exactly the same.

Comment: The sequence $(a_n)_{n\ge m}$  is the $same$ as the sequence $(a_{n-k})_{n\ge m+k}.$

Comment: If you want to be more convinced for theequation at the end, observe that $\lim_{N\to\infty} s_{N+k}=\lim_{N\to\infty} s_{N}$

Comment: If $\displaystyle \sum_{n=m}^{\infty} a_n$ makes sense then it can only converge to $0$. So the question sounds strange. Where did you find it?

Comment: ^^ this is in Tao's Analysis 1 book Proposition 7.2.14 (d)